# Edit content in ckeditor

Tags: php, ckeditor

iam using ckeditor in my website to add the content to the pages.
But I'm not able to understand how I get this content in ckeditor for editing it later...

How to load content into the ckeditor? Iam using the following code to load the editor:

```
    if ( !@file_exists( '../../ckeditor/ckeditor.php' ) )
    {
    if ( @file_exists('../../ckeditor/ckeditor.js') || @file_exists('../../../ckeditor/ckeditor_source.js') )
        printNotFound('CKEditor 3.1+');
    else
        printNotFound('CKEditor');
    }


include_once '../../ckeditor/ckeditor.php';
include_once '../../ckfinder/ckfinder.php';

// This is a check for the CKEditor class. If not defined, the paths in lines 57 and 70 must be checked.
if (!class_exists('CKEditor'))
{
    printNotFound('CKEditor');
}
else
{
 $ckeditor = new CKEditor();
 $ckeditor->basePath = '../../ckeditor/';
 $ckfinder = new CKFinder();
 $ckfinder->BasePath = '../../ckfinder/'; // Note: BasePath property in CKFinder class starts with capital letter
 $ckfinder->SetupCKEditorObject($ckeditor);
 $ckeditor->editor('message');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to pre-populate the `<textarea>` field with the appropriate (`htmlentities()` processed) HTML content. CKEditor will automatically fetch the data, and insert it into the WYSIWYG editor.

See the [Integration chapter in the developers guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration)

Comment: But iam not able to find where is the textarea in my code... i dont have it in my code.. the textarea is coming dynamically... i just included the ckeditor file.... I want something like: http://ckeditor.com/demo

Comment: @dskanth please edit your question and add the code you are using.

Comment: Edited my question.... added the code to load the editor... now what i dont understand is how to load some content into the editor by default

Comment: @dskanth where does that PHP class come from? Doesn't it come with documentation?

Comment: yes i hope it comes from documentation... but i saw a demo code and used it... I downloaded ckeditor and ckfinder and integrated them.,,

Comment: @dskanth I don't know the library you are using, so I don't know how to do it in that library. It *should* be in the documentation.

Comment: oh.. my goodness... i did not see the documentation link above, and after following those instructions , i could get what i wanted. Thanks a lot for the link... did not expect that the editor can be loaded using javascript. So simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

For those who not found the answer, the "editor" method of ckeditor allow to load default value

```
public function editor($name, $value = "", $config = array(), $events = array())
```

Just pass your default value in the second parameters.